# How to use CasperJS findOne function with two or more selectors?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I'm sorry..
this ariticle update..

Element is thought to be one, but found two or more.. sorry.. :)

```
<div class="rd_ft">
    <div id="prev_next">
        <a id="rd_prev" href="aaaa.html"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="rd_ft">
    <div id="prev_next">
        <a id="rd_prev" href="bbbb.html"></a>   <--- it will select this element only
    </div>
</div>
```

...........

```
var con_prev = 
    this.evaluate(function(){ 
        return __utils__.findOne('div[class="rd_ft"] div[id="prev_next"] a[id="rd_prev"]').getAttribute('href'); 
    });
```

It should not working this code..

current select data is aaaa.html.

I would like to know how to select the last element.

Comment: im not sure whats this casperjs is, but isnt the point of find**ONE** is to find, well, One, and not two or more? besides, to select multiple elements you separate them by a comma, not a space. space searches the next elements as children of the previous ones.

Comment: Now, this is invalid HTML. An id is supposed to be used only once in the DOM. Are you really sure this is how the DOM looks like?

Comment: Yes.
Some sites would like to write a post, then copy and paste the contents of the text.
Is there any way to solve?

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
findOne('div[class="rd_ft"] div[id="prev_next"] a[id="rd_prev"]')
```

with this:

```
findOne('div[class="rd_ft"], div[id="prev_next"], a[id="rd_prev"]')
```

the first version will search for elements that look like that:

```
<div class="rd_ft">
    <div id="prev_next">
        <a id="rd_prev"></a>   <--- it will select this element only
    </div>
</div>
```

the 2nd version will select 3 separate elements:

```
<div class="rd_ft"></div>
<div id="prev_next"></div>
<a id="rd_prev"></a>
```

**UPDATE**

i just had a second look at your question, and it appears that you might be asking the wrong question.

if you would like to select an `<a>` element as a child of the other two divs, then it will not work if your div has more than 1 class. you are testing for `div[class="rd_ft"]` which will work only if the div has **one** class. if your div has more than 1 class, you need to test it using a class selector `.` as follows: `div.rd_ft`

basically, you would want to use this:

```
findOne('div.rd_ft div[id="prev_next"] a[id="rd_prev"]')
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. i agree, but im not sure about casperjs's selector support, thats why i gave a plain answer on op's question without any extra adjustments. besides, i cant see a scenario where he would ever put an href attribute in a div element in the first place...

Comment: Generally it (PhantomJS) supports all CSS3 selectors, but some things are buggy such as `nth-child` and things like that, therefore it is good to use XPath in those cases.

Comment: i see. in that case i strongly believe op's language barrier cause him to phrase his question wrongly. i will update my answer.